# mysql don't return results if not from statement but from INDEX table or something

Tags: mysql

I think my question was a little confusing.....It confused me :)

Working on a media site as a take-over project and it has a custom CMS.  The client wants the ability to activate/deactivate media....sort of like Wordpress's publish/unpublish feature.

Instead of digging through all the code looking for mysql queries (which I'm not opposed to), I was wondering if you can add a sort of INDEX to a table that won't let it return result rows if that rows "active" column = let's say 0.

Just trying to be lazy and learn something at the same time, heh.

I don't need examples of queries to make it happen, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is called a "view". Here is a page describing how to create them in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html. However, in most cases you will still have to alter your code to use the view instead of the table.

Comment: That is actually really nice....It does seem you are right though about having to change the code to use the view instead of the table.  Unfortunately for me, it seems they are not on a VDS, as I got permission denied when trying to create a view :(

Answer (score 1):

You can consider create a view (which contains active record only)

**AND** swap the view name to actual table name instead, so you can achieve the negative filtering without changing any of your source code.

Comment: I was thinking about this too, but will inserts / updates still work?